# Regex to remove unwanted css

Tags: regex

I have a CSS that it's written with too many references, I wanted to remove those references before header work.

For example, I want to change this:

```
#x #y #header, #s #t #header{}
#header #a #b, #t #header{}
#k, #l,#x #y #header{}
```

And this is the output I am expecting:

```
#header, #header{}
#header #a #b, #header{}
#header{}
```

I tried this code in RegexPal but didn't have much success:

```
(.*)(?=#header)
```

I want to remove all elements which is coming BEFORE #header I can search and find multiple times but what this regex is doing is checking by last #header only not first one for example with this regex output is :

```
#header{}
#header{}
#header{}
```

Comment: sorry didn't get your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-greedy match, and throw in a look behind:

```
(?<=^|,).*?(?=#header)
```

See a [`live demo`](http://rubular.com/r/ORaGDjpIXG) of this regex matching the unwanted input of your sample text.

Explanation:

`.*` is greedy - it will match as much as it can, potentially skipping over `#header` to the next, but `.*?` is *reluctant* (aka non-greedy) and matches as little as possible - it won't skip over a `#header`.

`(?<=^|,)` is a look behind that asserts the input prior to the match is either the start of input or a comma - which allows a new match after commas.

Comment: matching nothing please check in regexpal :\

Comment: Check my link - it's matching correctly. Post a link to your regexpal example.

Comment: ok great please just 1 more thing please explain it to me what its doing because the main purpose of this question is also I wanted to know more about regex

Comment: well there's just 1 issue but in notepad++ also when using it its not working and if I remove < then it works but removing comma also

Comment: OK - added explanation. hope it helps. And is this for use with notepad++? If so, you should add that tag to the question.